# Reading shaders from .glsl files generates linking error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glew

I am following a textbook example that draws a square (half blue, half red) in the center of the window using shaders read from .glsl files but I get a linking error. I was able to draw the square before moving the shaders to separate files, so I suspect the problem is actually reading from the files. The program does draw the square but does not fill in the colors.

```
//Program 2.4

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#define numVAOs 1
GLuint renderingProgram;
GLuint vao[numVAOs];

/***********************************************************/
/****************Modules to Catch GLSL Errors***************/
/***********************************************************/

//Displays the contents of opengl's log when GLSL compilation failed
void printShaderLog(GLuint shader)
{
    int len = 0;
    int chWrittn = 0;
    char* log;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

    if (len > 0)
    {
        log = (char*)malloc(len);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, len, &chWrittn, log);

        std::cout << "Shader Info Log: " << log << std::endl;

        free(log);
    }
}

//displays the contents of opengl's log when glsl linking failed
void printProgramLog(int prog)
{
    int len = 0;
    int chWrittn = 0;
    char* log;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

    if (len > 0)
    {
        log = (char*)malloc(len);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(prog, len, &chWrittn, log);

        std::cout << "Program Info Log: " << log << std::endl;

        free(log);
    }
}

//Checks the opengl error flag for the occurrence of an opengl error
bool checkOpenGLError()
{
    bool foundError = false;
    int glErr = glGetError();

    while (glErr != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "glError: " << glErr << std::endl;
        foundError = true;
        glErr = glGetError();
    }
    return foundError;
}



//to read from glsl files
std::string readShaderSource(const char* filePath)
{
    std::string content;
    std::ifstream fileStream(filePath, std::ios::in);
    std::string line = "";

    while (!fileStream.fail())
    {
        getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }

    fileStream.close();
    return content;
}



GLuint createShaderProgram()
{
    GLint vertCompiled;
    GLint fragCompiled;
    GLint linked;

    GLuint vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    

    //read shader source from .glsl files
    std::string vertShaderStr = readShaderSource("vertShader.glsl");
    std::string fragShaderStr = readShaderSource("fragShader.glsl");
 

    const char* vertShaderSrc = vertShaderStr.c_str();
    const char* fragShaderSrc = fragShaderStr.c_str();

 
    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vertShaderSrc, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fragShaderSrc, NULL);


    //catch errors while compiling vShader
    glCompileShader(vShader);       //compiles shader
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertCompiled);
    if (vertCompiled != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "vertex compilation failed" << std::endl;
        printShaderLog(vShader);
    }

    //catch errors while compiling fShader
    glCompileShader(fShader);       //compiles shader
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetShaderiv(fShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fragCompiled);
    if (fragCompiled != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "fragment compilation failed" << std::endl;
        printShaderLog(fShader);
    }


    GLuint vfProgram = glCreateProgram();               

    //catch errors while linking shaders
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, vShader);                 
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(vfProgram);                          
    
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetProgramiv(vfProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
    if (linked != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "linking failed" << std::endl;
        printProgramLog(vfProgram);
    }

    return vfProgram;
}



//calls createShaderProgram(),
void init(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    renderingProgram = createShaderProgram();

    glGenVertexArrays(numVAOs, vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
}

void display(GLFWwindow* window, double currentTime)
{
    glUseProgram(renderingProgram); 
    glPointSize(30.0f); 

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);  
}




int main(void)
{
   
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 600, "Chapter2-program4", NULL, NULL);

 
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //Window or OpenGL context creation failed
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();        
        return -1;
    }


    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)               
    {
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    init(window);   //calls init function

    /* Rendering loop*/
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        /* Render here */
        display(window, glfwGetTime());

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();    
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

fragShader.glsl

```
#version 430
out vec4 color;
void main(void)
{
    if(gl_FragCoord.x < 300)
    {
        color = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); 
    }
    else
    {
        color = vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);
    }
}
```

vertShader.glsl

```
#version 430
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

[image: Console and window]

Comment: Are the `*.glsl` files in your program's current working directory?

Comment: @G.M. Yes, they are.

Comment: Please show the glsl link error(s) verbatim.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my console with the link error and the square it generates.

Comment: `glGetShaderInfoLog` is only for _shader_ objects, **not** for _program_ objects.